# Extra space is created when a button is placed directly below a text area

Tags: html, css

When placing a button directly below a text area, extra space is created in both Chrome and Firefox (I haven't tested other browsers). Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JTmrk/) that replicates the issue. Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <button></button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 125px;
}
textarea {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: red;
    resize: none;
}
button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 25px;
    border: none;
    background: blue;
    margin: 0;
    padding;
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `display` property on the `textarea` to `block` and they should line up without a gap in-between. In general when I have some HTML elements not lining-up properly, I play with the `display` property as it's usually the culprit.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8kzpf/

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks! That's weird. I've seen this issue in the horizontal direction, but never the vertical direction...

Comment: It's not the culprit in this case - it's the default `vertical-align` value of baseline for elements in the inline formatting context.

Comment: @Adrift Looks like there are several ways to skin this cat, do you suggest they all affect `vertical-align` which is the real culprit? I am unfamiliar with why changing the `display` property works, it's just been my go-to for a while.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1 - Add `display:block` to all childs.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/JTmrk/2/

2 - Set `font-size:0` on parent div and reset it (e.g. `font-size:16px`) on all childs.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/JTmrk/3/

3 - Set `float:left` and `clear:both` to all childs.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/JTmrk/5/